# How to add this xml data to dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, ado.net

previously my xml was like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <supplier>
    <s_code>1</s_code>
    <net_weight>100</net_weight>
    <rate>100.00</rate>
  </supplier>

  <supplier>
    <s_code>2</s_code>
    <net_weight>500</net_weight>
    <rate>150.00</rate>
  </supplier>
</root>
```

so i created a dataset and added columns similar to this and used this code to load data into dataset and use dataset to create crystal report.

```
    DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
    reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/data.xml");

    DataSet dset = new DataSet1();
    dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]);

    ReportDocument report = new CrystalReport1();
    report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
    reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
```

so now i need to add more information to report and xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <supplier>
    <s_code>1</s_code>
    <net_weight>100</net_weight>
    <rate>100.00</rate>

    <items>
      <item_code>SKU001</items_code>
      <price>100</price>
    </items>
    <items>
      <item_code>SKU002</items_code>
      <price>200</price>
    </items>

  </supplier>

  <supplier>
    <s_code>2</s_code>
    <net_weight>500</net_weight>
    <rate>150.00</rate>

    <items>
      <item_code>SKU001</items_code>
      <price>100</price>
    </items>

  </supplier>

</root>
```

so any idea how to insert items into a dataset and use it in report?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your dataset with **nested relations**. 
See [Nesting DataRelations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for details.

You can do this with the vs2002 .. vs2010 dataset designer:

- create the table `supplier` and `items`

  - make shure both tables have a field `s_code`
- create a relation between table `supplier` and `items`

  - use field `s_code` as relation link
  - mark the relation as **nested**

After executing your code the items should be below their parents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now im getting 3 records for above xml, and any idea how to generate 2 pages for those 3 records?

Comment: what do you mean by `2 pages`? if you mean suplier 1 with 2 sub-items and supplier 2 with on subitem, your relation needs a foreign key that is identical in suplier and items.

Comment: yes. i modified xml to contain <s_code></s_code> inside items

Comment: still there is 3 pages though

Comment: yes also had to use grouping feature to show item data to each relevant supplier